# Match month from financial year range

Tags: php

I have quite different problem while implementing financial year system. 
I have financial year started from 01-04-2019 to 31-03-2020 (Indian fin. year). Now what i want to check if the previous months are locked before user can enter in current year. Ex

This is October - 10th month.

Database Design:

[image]

From above i want to get the months which LOCKED =0.

I.e. if current month is 10 then system will only check from month 4 to month 9. Similarly if month is 2 then it will check from 4 to 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if i understand you correctly, you want to display the month which are locked.
In my case, i will use if statement to declare all the month and execute a sql query to check for the months which are locked from 4 to the month base on the current month.

```
if($month == "10"){ //declared the month using number (1-12)
    $getmonths = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tablename BETWEEN month 4 and 9 WHERE locked = '0'") //i use between to get from month 4 to month 9
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($row = $getmonths->fetch_assoc()){
        $month = $row['month'];
        print_r($month);} //i print out the months
    }
    else if($month == "2"){
        $getmonths = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tablename BETWEEN month 4 and 1 WHERE locked = '0'") //i use between to get from month 4 to month 1
        or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($row = $getmonths->fetch_assoc()){
        $month = $row['month'];
        print_r($month);}
        }else{    
    echo"<script>alert('No Records Match...');</script>";
}
```

Another Method for my query is using date format.

```
SELECT * FROM `dt_tb` WHERE month(dt) between '02' and '08'
```

The above query will return records of all the months between February and August of any year. We can specify the year also along with the months like this

```
SELECT * FROM `dt_tb` WHERE month(dt) between '02' and '08' and year(dt) between 2019 and 2020
```

I hope am able to solve answer your question.?

Comment: Yes you are correct for specific month, but in my case i want to use dynamic months, i.e. some times 4,5 etc. I will be verifying these data in each month so need to compare with current running month.

Also i need to keep in mind that financial year can get changed i.e. as of now it is 01-04-YYYY to 31-03-YYYY but in future if it gets changed to 01-01_-YYYY to 31-12-YYYY then also it should be work

Comment: With the above code, you can use those months as variable to query the db table. while selecting month range.